# VB NET image as button

Tags: vb.net, button

I'm going to change the image of button_original to button_clicked's image.
how do I change the image(button) when I click them ?
Should I need to use picture box anything else ?

Comment: are you using an image button or a general button ? ASP.NET or Winforms ?

Comment: according to me its is not possible as Image Control Does not have "Click" property. you need to find some other way

Answer (score 1):

In vb.NET, if you're using an image on a button, to change it, you can change the `property Image` of the button in the `Button_Click()` event.

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click

     Button.Image = ... <- your image

 End Sub
```